# SSD not recognised by MacBook Air

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, disk-format

I changed the motherboard of a MacBook Air A1465 because the previous one was faulty and the Mac didn't even start.

Now the machine starts but when I try to install, neither the macOS installer app nor Disk Utility seem to recognise it.

I then searched online and found out that you can use the terminal and see if the computer recognises the SSD by using the command:

```
diskutil list
```

[image: the diskutil list]

The SSD gets listed but just doesn't show in the Disk Utility (maybe because it's not formatted in the right way) so I used this command to initialise the SSD as JHFS+ volume.

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ myDisk /dev/disk22
```

the process starts but it is interrupted by this error

```
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

after this error the disk disappears even from the terminal

disk22 info's are:

```
Device identifier : disk22
Device node: /dev/disk22
Whole :   yes
Part of whole :   disk22
Device / Media Name: APPLE SSD TS0128F
Volume Name: Not applicable (no file system)
Mounted : Not applicable (no file system)
File System: None
Content (IOContent): None 
OS Can be installed No
Media Type: Generic
Protocol: PCI
```

macOS Recovery software version:

```
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion:  10.15.2
BuildVersion: 19C57
```

It's a MacBook Air Mid 2013 without any OS installed yet since I just changed the motherboard, but is suitable for installing Catalina.

Comment: Is `/dev/disk22` a typo?  How are you trying this?  From recovery or USB installer?  Please update question with output of `diskutil list` and add your MacBook and macOS versions.

Comment: @lx07 I'm trying this form recovery, I changed the motherboard so I'm doing this using the terminal given in the disk utility. No, /dev/disk22 it's not a typo since the diskutil list is made of a lot of small disks and eventually the last one that is the right one. I cannot give you the entire diskutil since it's on another device and I don't know how to copy it on this one. but I'll add disk22 info

Comment: @Allan posted it in second EDIT

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I should have said use the command `diskutil list | pbcopy` so you can paste the *text* rather than a graphic as it allows the content to be searchable.  If you can fix that, it would be great.  In any event...`disk22` is definitely your internal SSD.  Try the command `diskutil zerodisk force /dev/disk22`.  I'm assuming you're booting an installer or in Recovery Mode.

Comment: @klanomath I add in 3rd EDIT

Comment: @Allan I did `diskutil zero disk force /dev/disk22` but it is interrupted by the Error code : 
`Error: -69879: Couldn't open disk`
`Underlying error: 2`

Comment: @Allan After the error occurred the Disk disappears from the list of disks. I have to restart all the recovery mode, clicking Command-Option-R when the Mac boots. Then the disk appears again

Comment: I'm doing recovery process again right now to get to the installation page where I can access the terminal one more time, then I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Ok Cool.  The comments are getting long, so ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=apple.stackexchange.com) by addressing me *@Allan*  I'll try to get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: @Allan thanks so much man, I tried but I can't find you tho

Comment: Try this room:  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/102891/ssd-not-recognised-by-macbook-air?tab=general

Comment: Thank you ! I'll let you know as soon as possible